# Where do I find the docs for lodash/fp package?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I was looking at the docs for lodash. There is a function called "filter", but it is used in a different way than the "filter" from `import filter from "lodash/fp/filter";`. For example, this code does not work:

```
import filter from "lodash/fp/filter";

var users = [
  { user: "barney", age: 36, active: true },
  { user: "fred", age: 40, active: false }
];

const newUsers = filter(users, function (o) {
  return !o.active;
});

console.log(newUsers);
```

However, I can't seem to find the cos for "import filter from "lodash/fp/filter";

Comment: The "fp guide" link on the top right corner of the home - https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jfmengels/6b973b69c491375117dc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lodash/fp function are iteratee (the callback function) first, data last, and curried, so you can create new functions, and then supply the data:

```js
const { filter } = _; // import { filter } fron 'lodash/fp'

const filterActiveUsers = filter(o =>  !o.active);

const users = [
  { user: "barney", age: 36, active: true },
  { user: "fred", age: 40, active: false }
];

console.log(filterActiveUsers(users));

// which is identical to

console.log(filter(o => !o.active, users));
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```